# Change logo based on incoming domain

Tags: php, html, function, redirect

**I am posting here for generic coding support rather than WordPress. I originally posted this on the [WordPress Development Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/213930/change-logo-based-on-incoming-domain?noredirect=1#comment311322_213930) and was supported until it was no longer a WordPress related matter.**

The agency I work for are trying to get a client's logo to change based upon the incoming URL.

Now, we have 4 different URLs, therefore 4 different logos.

Currently, we are using an `if/else` statement, and the default logo is being bought through to the header.

The `if/else` statement we are using is as follows:

```
<?php 
            if(!empty($image)) {
                 echo '<h1>WEBSITE_NAME_HERE</h1>';
             }
             else {
                 echo '<img src="'.logoSwap().'" alt="Localised Logo">';
                }
        ?>
```

The problem now lies with the logo not actually changing.

We are using a `switch/case` statement to actually specify the image paths and the incoming domains, and in order for the `logoSwap()` function to actually be declared:

```
<?php
function logoSwap(){
switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    case 'WEBSITE_URL_HERE.com': 
        $logo = "WEBSITE_URL_HERE/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/logo-red.png";
    break;
    case 'www.WEBSITE_URL_HERE.com':
        $logo = "WEBSITE_URL_HERE/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/logo-red.png";
    break;
    case 'WEBSITE_URL_HERE.co.uk':
        $logo = "WEBSITE_URL_HERE/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/logo.png";
    break;
    case 'www.WEBSITE_URL_HERE.co.uk':
        $logo = "WEBSITE_URL_HERE/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/logo.png";
    break;
    default:
        $logo = "WEBSITE_URL_HERE/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/logo.png";
    break;
}
    return $logo;
}
?>
```

The `.com` domain is using a 301 redirect which is pulling it directly to the .co.uk domain, however the logo isn't changing when accessed from the `.com` domain. Could it simply be the fact that it is coming in via a 301 redirect?

For example, I will type in `mywebsite.com` and I will get redirected to `mywebsite.co.uk`, however it displays the same logo on both.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If there is a redirect, then `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` will be the redirected to url, eg the `.co.uk`. You could try checking the referrer instead

Comment: @Dropout I think it's just changed that when I posted it.

Comment: @Steve I'll have a look into that soon and see whether I need more support with that.

We've seen it done elsewhere, but unfortunately that has been done via the website being duplicated and hosted on both domains which is not what we want to do, as Google will then index both sites and put black marks against the sites for being identical.

Comment: Actually, thinking about it, i would set up the 301 redirect to just set a cookie (eg com=1) then do the redirect. Your `logoSwap()` function then becomes a simple if cookie set, show red, else show normal

Comment: How would I go about setting up the cookies. I've never actually had to do anything with cookies apart from displaying a cookie notice to say they were being used.

Comment: That depends - how you are performing the redirect?

Comment: The redirect is done via the registrar, which in this case is 123-reg. I could potentially drop a file into the directory for the `.com` domain on our server instead should that be the way I need to do it.